# How to strip whitespace in string in TCL?

Tags: string, whitespace, tcl

I need to strip leading and trailing whitespace from a string in TCL. How?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this -

> **string trim** *string* ?*chars*?
>
> Returns a value equal to *string* except that any leading or trailing characters from the set given by *chars* are removed. If *chars* is not specified then white space is removed (spaces, tabs, newlines, and carriage returns).

Original Source :- http://wiki.tcl.tk/10174

Comment: There's also `string trimleft` and `string trimright` when you only want to trim one end.

Comment: Here's an example how the *chars* argument works: trim (english) vowels from the left and right of a string: `set str "each patio"; puts [string trim $str "aeiou"]` outputs `ch pat`

Answer (score 0):

try this. this will remove all the withe spaces

```
[string map {" " ""} $a];
```

a is your string

Comment: He only wants to strip leading and tailing whitespace. Also you don't remove other types of whitespace, like tabulator, newline...